# Higher-order gauge coupling terms in the Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-invariance

In QFT, one works with Lagrangians that are invariant with respect to a certain symmetry. Out of this invariance, one is able to write down interaction terms at first order in the gauge couplings. The invariance we are talking about is though only guaranteed up to the first order, in the expansion of the transformation operator.

My question is: What if we design Lagrangians invariant under higher orders, say the second (assuming this possible)? Would this lead to the correct form of the higher order interaction processes?

Comment: If you are wondering why we always examine the invariance under continuous (Lie) symmetries only up to first order in the continuous parameter, this suffices because invariance under the Lie algebra (which is the first order expansion of the symmetry) rigorously implies invariance under the full Lie group.

Comment: Uhm, ok. But that said, would we be able to use the higher orders in the expansion (higher order derivatives) to infer something about the structure of high order interactions?

Comment: Wait...are talking about *higher order expansions* of the symmetry (as I thought), or about the appearence of higher order derivatives of the fields in the Lagrangian?

Comment: Aren't they the same thing?

Comment: Not that I can see. Perhaps you could write an example of what you are thinking about in your question?

Comment: Alright sorry I made a mistake. Please forget about the derivatives in my first comment and consider higher orders in the expansion of the transformation. Would they have a meaning?

Comment: A finite transformation can be formally understood as applying a product of the first order transformations, like a famous exponential $\rm{e}^x=(1+x/N)^N,\, N\to\infty$. If the invariance holds for an infinitesimal transformation, it will hold for a finite one too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [Lie theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_theory).

When we have got a continuous symmetry, the means the symmetry group is a [Lie group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) $G$. Saying that the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ is invariant under $G$ means that $\rho(g)(\mathcal{L}) = \mathcal{L}\;\forall\; g \in G$, where $\rho$ is the [representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_of_a_group) the Lagrangian transforms in.

The "expansion to first order" physicists so often do is just switching from the action of $g$ to the action of its associated element in the [Lie algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra). Every (well, not always *every*, but that's a technicality) element of the group is *generated* by the basis vectors $T^a$ of the Lie algebra by

$$ g = \mathrm{exp}(\phi^a T^a)$$

with one $\phi^a$ as coefficient for every $T^a$. This is, abstractly, *not* the exponential function we are used to, but for matrix groups, it turns out to be. The physicists approach is now to expand the exponential naively as

$$ \mathrm{e}^{\phi^a T^a} = 1 + \phi^a T^a + \mathcal{O}(\phi^2)$$

and henceforth consider the transformation under the *infinitesimal* symmetry $1 + \phi^a T^a$ instead of the group element. Every representation $\rho$ of the Lie group induces as representation $\mathrm{d}\rho$ of the Lie algebra, so we examine $(1 + \phi^a \mathrm{d}\rho(T^a))v$ for a vector $v$ whose transformation we are interested in. Invariance obviously means then that $\mathrm{d}\rho(T^a)v = 0$ for all $T^a$, since it must hold for arbitrary $\phi$. It follows that also the higher orders of the expansion would simply vanish when applied to $v$, you gain no new insights considering them, and you get $\rho(\mathrm{e}^{\phi^a T^a})v = v$ iff $\mathrm{d}\rho(T^a) v = 0$ from the first order alone.

More generally, the "higher order" terms in the expansion will *not* be elements of the Lie algebra, but of its [universal enveloping algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra), which has not really something to do with our symmetry. The *Lie algebra* encodes all you need to know about infinitesimal transformations, and the *Lie group* encodes all you need to know about "finite" transformations.

It is very important to note that we are not doing an *approximation* when considering the Lie algebra - the connection between Lie algebra and Lie group is rigorous and *does not need* the power series of the exponential to be mathematically meaningful. The physicist's way of saying "expand to first order" is just a way to avoid all that pesky group theory while still getting the right results.